# How do I save the value of this PHP dropdown using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have this dropdown menu in PHP and I would like to get the selected value in jQuery:

```
        <p>
            Choose device type :
            <?php
            echo "<select id='type_id_selected' name='device_type_id'>";
            echo "<option value='Select'>Select</option>";
            foreach ($dev_type_results as $row) {
                echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
            }
            echo "</select>"; ?>
        </p>
```

and I tried with this jQuery code but didn't work:

```
            <script>
            $('#type_id_selected').change(function() {
                var data = "";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    data: "value=" + $(this).val(),
                    async: false,
                    success: function(response) {
                        data = response;
                        return response;
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        alert('Error occured');
                    }
                });
                var select = $('equipe1');
                select.empty();
                $.each(array, function(index, value) {
                    select.append(
                        $('<option></option>').val(value).html(value)
                    );
                });
            });
        </script>
```

EDIT: I changed the jquery code and now I am able to get the data in jQuery, however, I dont know how to save the value somehow that I can access in PHP code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("select.device_type_id").change(function() {
            var selectedType = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
          //  access selectedType in PHP
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: And? Output `$(this).val()`, what's in it?

Comment: Also why async=false? Very poor practice

Comment: For data in ajax code try data:{value:$(this).val()}. But what is this var select = $('equipe1');?

Comment: "It didn't work" is not a good description. Show us what you have tried. What does console log give you? any errors? etc. right now it is vague at best

Comment: Url is missing for the ajax request too.

Comment: @Hardood Defaults to the current page

Comment: @kerbholz I didn't see php snippet to process the ajax request in the current page, that is why i mentioned it.

Comment: @u_mulder I just edited the code

Comment: @Hardood please see the edited code, the updated code is working but how to access it in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the values in JS and send an AJAX POST request to your PHP file.
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Testing</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('select.unit').change(function() {
                let selectedUnit = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
                console.log(selectedUnit)
                $.ajax({
                    url: "./data.php",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: {
                        unit: selectedUnit
                    },
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(html) {
                        $('#confirmation').html(html);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <select id="choose-first-unit" class="span-four unit">
            <option value="m3">cubic meters</option>
            <option value="cm3">cubic centimeters/milliliters</option>
            <option value="dm3">cubic decimeters/litres</option>
            <option value="hl">hectolitres</option>
            <option value="cl">centilitres</option>
       </select>
    <div id="confirmation"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

PHP Code: for first PHP File

```
<?php
session_start();
$unit = $_POST['unit'];
$_SESSION['unit'] = $unit;
?>
```

And in the other file where you want to access the value

```
session_start();
$data = $_SESSION['unit'];
```

Comment: The OP has not provided further information as to what works and doesn't work. Your answer isn't helpful

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi check the edited code, now I want to retrieve that value in PHP

Comment: @mr.fartty you can access the value in PHP by using
<?php $_POST['data']; ?>

Comment: @mr.fartty you have to mention the URL of the file in which you want to get the value of the PHP file as seen in my script tag you can see I have a URL parameter.

Comment: @P.Mubeen I want to access it in two different pages.

Comment: okay you can use session variable to store it in a session variable and then access it in other file using the session variable.

Comment: @P.Mubeen can you please post a short snippet how to do that because I am totally lost

Comment: @mr.fartty yes I have edited in the PHP code above in my answer check there.

Comment: @P.Mubeen I am confused about `url: "./data.php",` do I really need it then since I am saving it in a Session which is accessible anywhere?

Comment: @mr.fartty yes you do need it. That tells the browser which PHP script to send the data to. Only PHP can save it in the session (because PHP runs on the server, and the Session is on the server, whereas Javascript is in the browser and cannot access it directly). So you have to specify which PHP script is going to be doing the saving.

Comment: @ADyson somebody give this man a cookie, thanks man you fixed it!

Comment: @mr.fartty fixed what? I didn't suggest any changes, I just explained the concept. But thanks anyway, glad you got it working :-).

Comment: @mr.fartty Kudos you got it working.